# Syntax error: Missing operand before '=' operator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code like this:

```
DataRow[] drClaimCPT;
drClaimCPT = dtCpt.Select("CLAIM_NUMBER == " + claimNo + "");
```

When I run, I got an error:

```
Syntax error: Missing operand before '=' operator.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: or `dtCpt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("CLAIM_NUMBER")==claimNo)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work for you if type is integer:

```
drClaimCPT = dtCpt.Select("CLAIM_NUMBER = " + claimNo + "");
```

for string:

```
drClaimCPT = dtCpt.Select("CLAIM_NUMBER = '" + claimNo + "'");
```

Comment: Beat me with 2 seconds `:)`

Comment: and for boolean fields?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `claimNo` is `number`, the right syntax is;

```
dtCpt.Select("CLAIM_NUMBER = " + claimNo + "");
```

[`DataTable.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses same rules with [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by the way.

If your `claimNo` is a `string`, you should use single quotes with it.

```
dtCpt.Select("CLAIM_NUMBER = 'claimNo'");
```

From *documentation*;

> User-Defined Values
>
> User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with
>   column values. **String values should be enclosed within single
>   quotation marks**

Answer (score 1):

Your actual issue was using double '=' - that is the coding equals - rememebr it is SQL equals - so only it should be "CLAIM_NUMBER **=** claimNo" , not "CLAIM_NUMBER **==** claimNo".